# Visual Studio 2015: Build C++ 11 library for Android

Tags: android, c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, android-ndk

I'm working on porting [this](https://github.com/iWiggins/LOGIC/tree/mobile) digital logic library to Android. However, I keep getting build errors involving missing functions from standard libraries like CMath, or missing C++11 libraries when trying to compile the Android project. Searching has revealed that issues with building C++ for Android in Visual Studio are rather common, but none of the suggestions I have found so far have helped. [Here](https://github.com/iWiggins/LOGIC/tree/mobile/LogicM/LogicM.Android) is the project with the build errors.

I have tried changing the target platform, changing the platform toolset, and changing the use of STL. Various combinations of the settings. I can't seem to get anything building.

Should I just give up on Visual Studio for my mobile C++ code and build those libraries elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a new branch with only Android code (as opposed to the previous cross platform mobile branch) and further playing with settings and searching, I arrived at the solution. These settings will allow the code to compile:

Compiler: Clang 3.8

Use of STL: GNU STL Static library

C++ Language Standard: C++11

Linker Command Line Additional Options: -lm

The designation that made it work was the -lm linker option to ensure it was properly linking the math library.